# command line arguments from file

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script for which I expect to pass quite  few arguments in the command line. Having many arguments is not a problem since it is configured as a scheduled task but I'd like to make things easier for support people so that if ever they need to run the script from command line they have less things to type.

So, I am considering the option to have the arguments in a text file, either using Java-style properties file with key/value pairs in each line, or a simple XML file that would have one element per argument with a name element and a value element.

```
arg1=value1
arg2=value2
```

I'm interested with the views of PowerShell experts on the two options and also if this is the right thing to do.

Thanks

Comment: Some thoughts from Keith Hill on how this can be achieved with XML http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2006/06/01/creating-and-using-a-configuration-file-for-your-powershell-scripts/. My personal opinion though would be to avoid XML if 'support' people are going to be editing it. Way too easy to make a mistake leading to malformed XML.

Comment: @andyb I agree with your views and that is why i"m strongly inclined towards the key/value items in a plain text file and then read the file contents in a hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the ini file approach, you can easily parse the ini data like so:

```
$ini = ConvertFrom-StringData (Get-Content .\args.ini -raw)
$ini.arg1
```

The one downside to this approach is that all the arg types are `string` this works fine for strings and even numbers AFAICT.  Where it falls down is with `[switch]` args.  Passing `True` or `$true` doesn't have the desired effect.

Another approach is to put the args in a `.ps1` file and execute it to get back a hashtable with all the args that you can then splat e.g:

```
-- args.ps1 --
@{
ComputerName = 'localhost'
Name = 'foo'
ThrottleLimit = 50
EnableNetworkAccess = $true
}

$cmdArgs = .\args.ps1
$s = New-PSSession @cmdArgs
```

Comment: That's nice. Hadn't come across that cmdlet before. Why is the `-raw` necessary? I guess because the cmdlet only processes a single string; not a collection.

Comment: If you are using powershell 2.0 the -raw can be replaced with (Get-Content .\args.ini | out-string)

Comment: Found this script to process INI files at http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/08/20/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file.aspx for those who want to take this idea further

Answer (score 0):

To extend Keith's answer slightly, it's possible to set actual variables based on the values from the config file e.g.

```
$ini = ConvertFrom-StringData (Get-Content .\args.ini -raw)
$ini.keys | foreach-object { set-variable -name $_ -value $ini.Item($_) }
```

So a file containing

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

When processed with above code should lead to three variables being created:

```
$a = 1, $b = 2, $c = 3
```

I expect this would work for simple string values, but i'm fairly sure it would not be 'smart' enough to convert, say `myArray = 1,2,3,4,5` into an actual array.

Comment: The benefit of having $ini as a hashtable rather than separate args is that you can then splat all those args at once e.g. `some-command @ini`.